# Assigning an array from another array [Encrypter Problems]

Tags: python, arrays, variables, encryption

My code [Only related to the 'EncryptString' function]:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

c = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
nc = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
al = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
at = ["b","m","f","s","c","v","e","l","d","n","t","a","w","g","p","o","r","q","k","h","u","x","i","y","j","z"]

def GoE():
    EnteredText = (e1.get())
    if EnteredText != ".!entry":
        print("Encrypting")
        #try:
        print(EnteredText, e1)
        print("Attempting to Encrypt")
        EnteredText.lower()
        c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6], c[7], c[8], c[9], c[10], c[11], c[12], c[13], c[14], c[15], c[16], c[17], c[18], c[19], c[20], c[21], c[22], c[23], c[24], c[25], c[26], c[27], c[28], c[29], c[30], c[31] = EnteredText
        EncryptString()


def Encrypter():
    print("Encrypter Selected")
    screen2.title("Encrypter")
    a = Label(screen2, text="Text to be Encrypted (SUM OF CHARACTERS MUST BE 32)").grid(row=1, column=0)
    e1.grid(row=2, column=0)
    button2 = Button(screen2, text="Enter", command=GoE).grid(row=3, column=0)

def EncryptString():
    count = 0
    letterPos = 0
    poo = 0
    print('1')
    test2 = 0
    while test2 <= 31:
        print(c[test2])
        test2 = test2 + 1
    time.sleep(10)
        while poo <= 31:
            while count <= 31:
                print(str(count))
                if c[count] == al[letterPos]:
                    nc[count] = at[letterPos]
                    print('1.3')
                    print(nc[count])
                else:
                    if letterPos == 25:
                        print('Alphabet Completed')
                        letterPos = 0
                    else:
                        letterPos = letterPos + 1
                        print('1.2')
                count = count + 1
                print('Count = ' + str(count))
            count = 0
            poo = poo + 1
        test = test + 1
    num = 0
    while num <= 31:
        print(nc[num])
        num = num + 1





MenuScreen()
```

The main lines that cause the error are:

```
        while poo <= 31:
            while count <= 31:
                print(str(count))
                if c[count] == al[letterPos]:
                    nc[count] = at[letterPos]
                    print('1.3')
                    print(nc[count])
                else:
                    if letterPos == 25:
                        print('Alphabet Completed')
                        letterPos = 0
                    else:
                        letterPos = letterPos + 1
                        print('1.2')
                count = count + 1
                print('Count = ' + str(count))
            count = 0
            poo = poo + 1
        test = test + 1
```

Personally I think it is something to do with:

```
if c[count] == al[letterPos]:
    nc[count] = at[letterPos]
```

It should encrypt 32 characters of text, and print them at the end. 
The text I am trying to encrypt is 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzssssss', it will encrypt the 'a' and print 'b', and will encrypt the 'ssssss', and outputs 'kkkkkk'. The rest just gets printed out as ' ', (a blank space). You can use any of the patches of code to try and detect the problem.
I've been trying to spot a problem for days but can't work it out. Would be greatly appreciated. I don't know whether I'm approaching it wrong or just being a bit stupid. It may just be easier to start it again. I think that I am not looping / looping to much, and that it only cycles through one letter per character inputted. My qestion basically is, am I on the right lines? and is there any improvements to make, to make it work?

Comment: What does this problem have to do with tkinter? Is the problem with the encoding, or with the GUI? Please try to reduce the problem down to as few lines as possible and create a [mcve].

Comment: Edited the question as best I can.

Comment: Ok, so it appears this question has nothing to do with tkinter. I recommend getting rid of all of the tkinter code if the problem is actually in the non-tkinter block of code.

Comment: This is probably unrelated to the question that you asked, but it's normally a bad idea to create more than once instance of `Tk`. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Yes, it is unrelated, but helpful to know.